# Not able to do sudo apt-get update with errors from gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu focal Release

Tags: 20.04

```
Hit:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Hit:3 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam beta InRelease                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                           
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:9 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:10 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release                                                             
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                 
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu focal InRelease                                 
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu focal Release                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu focal Release                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu focal Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Err:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease    
  Temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done           
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
(base)  ✘ sriharsha@B550-AORUS  ~ 
```

Comment: You are adding PPAs that have no packages for your release of Ubuntu. Why are you doing that?

Comment: The problem was only from one of the focal packages, I added other one to be safe. So the solution is to untick all the PPA's which does not have a release ?